# Login with Email code error

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

Why I cannot manage to get my login working..

**views.py**

```
def candidate_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       email = request.POST.get('email')
       password = request.POST.get('password')

       user = authenticate(email=email,password=password)

       if user:
          if user.is_active & user.check_password(password):
             login(request,user)
             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
          else:
             HttpResponse("Account not active, please contact Admin")
       else:
          print("Someone tried to login and failed")
          return HttpResponse("Invalid login detailed supplied!")
     else:
        return render(request,'candidate_login.html',{})
```

When I try to login I get the `error` message : **Invalid login detailed supplied!**

Could you please help me to make it work ? 
Thk you very much
Raphael

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.


class MyUser(AbstractUser):
   is_hr = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_candidate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   is_employee = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   company = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
```

Comment: Not the problem, but you don't need to call `user.check_password`; that's already done in `authenticate`. And anyway, in Python the boolean and is just `and`, not `&`.

Comment: Is email being used as username? Have you used a custom `User` model?

Comment: Hi Sachin, yes I used a custom user model ! I edited my post yo show my model.py. What do you mean by using email as username ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[authenticate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate)    takes username & password to verify. you can directly filter User model to fetch user linked with given email and then check_password function to verify password.

```
def candidate_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       email = request.POST.get('email')
       password = request.POST.get('password')

       user = User.objects.filter(email=email)

       if user:
          user=user[0]
          if user.is_active & user.check_password(password):
             login(request,user)
             return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
          else:
             HttpResponse("Account not active, please contact Admin")
       else:
          print("Someone tried to login and failed")
          return HttpResponse("Invalid login detailed supplied!")
     else:
        return render(request,'candidate_login.html',{})
```

Comment: Awsome !! Thx you so much it worked !
I just had to change user = MyUser.objects.filter(email=email) since I use a custom model